# Non square matrices and spectrum of $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

There is a known theorem (true in the general context of Banach algebras) that if $a,b \in A$ (where $A$ is a Banach algebra) then $\sigma(ab) \cup \{0\}=\sigma(ba) \cup \{0\}$ where $\sigma$ is the spectrum. I wonder whether the same result is true in the specific context of finite dimensional spaces, i.e. $a,b$ are matrices but *we don't assume that they are square matrices*. We only assume that $a,b$ are such that $ab$ and $ba$ make sense, say $a$ is $m \times n$ and $b$ is $n \times m$ matrix.

Comment: I think this follows immediately by expressing matrices A and B as their Singular Value Decompositions.

Comment: How does the SVD have any bearing on this?

Comment: My previous suggestion does not hold. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, if $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$, $m \ge n$, the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices) of $AB$ is $\lambda^{m-n}$ times the characteristic polynomial of $BA$.

Comment: The proof you pointed to implies that in the square case, both products share not only their spectra, but also all of their algebraic invariants (e.g., eigenvalue multiplicities). Thus in the non-square case the algebraic invariants of both products differ only by "adding" an $m-n$ multiplicity of the trivial eigenvalue. @robert-israel, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Cool. Thanks!    :-)